# L'emploi populaire « en arracher » : depuis quand etc. ?

Tags: sens, verbes, locutions, origine-ou-raison, registre

> Il/elle *en arrache*.

L'idée de *difficulté* :

> - (A.) Le sujet désigne généralement une personne, une manifestation de la    personne, parfois une force naturelle ou mécanique; un objet 
>     secondaire, la préposition *à* précise, quand il y a lieu, la personne à qui on a enlevé quelque chose.
>
>   - (1.) L'objet désigne une chose concrète.
>
>     - (a.) Une plante qui tient au sol par ses racines ou ses tubercules, etc.    Déraciner, extraire du sol avec effort. ***Arracher
>         les pommes de terre, arracher les vignes***. Anton. *planter*. [...]
>
>       - − Populaire. *En arracher*. **Avoir des difficultés.**
>
> [Trésor de la langue française informatisé TLFi, « [arracher](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/arracher) »,
>   extraits de la présentation du dictionnaire adaptés, je souligne ]

- Depuis quand a-t-on cet emploi populaire, avec le pronom *en*,
  signifiant « avoir des difficultés » ; peut-on donner un exemple contemporain de son origine ?
- Est-ce davantage l'agriculture (*cueillir*) ou l'entretien de la
  propriété en général (*entretenir*) qui rend courante l'action qui
  inspire cet emploi ; peut-on préciser de quel genre de contexte/lieu
  provient la locution et ce qui ferait qu'elle est *populaire* ?

Comment: De nos jours cette expression est considérée comme un [québécisme](https://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/trente-expressions-pure-laine/) (je la comprends mais ne l'utilise pas et ne connaît personne qui l'utilise, je ne l'ai vu que sur des écrits québécois), j'aimerais donc savoir si c'est une survivance d'un emploi désormais désuet dans l'Hexagone ou une création québécoise, ce que la réponse à ta question nous apprendra j'espère.

Comment: @Laure Ah, tiens, possiblement une survivance, souvent le TLFi donne des indications quand c'est uniquement au Canada etc. ex. [_maganer_](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/maganer), [_icite_](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/icite) mais la présentation au TLFi n'est pas uniforme... Le GPFC dit « M.s., Poitou. ».

Answer (score 2):

Sans faire de doute que, dans l'esprit de beaucoup de locuteurs contemporains, ce *en arracher* est un raccourci de sa forme pronominale ***s***'en arracher.
Ce qui le ferait somme toute relativement récent... par rapport à ce que **je crois** être son authentique origine qu'il faudrait aller chercher bien avant le... : XVI<sup>è</sup>.

Bien avant dans la mesure où il se trouve déjà usuel dans la bouche des écoliers de l'époque qui... ayant tâté du fouet, *en avaient bien arraché*.

J'en veux pour preuve le *De Corrupti Sermonis Emendatione* de Mathurin Cordier dans lequel ce très pédagogue professeur s'était attaché à traduire en latin les expressions quotidiennes de ses potaches.

Je cite (à la page 70(2) de l'édition de 1536) : *Tu bene arrachauisti. Tu en as bien arrache. Cest à dire, tu as este bien fesse.*

Voilà, des écoliers, au XVI<sup>è</sup> voire avant, en proie à de sérieuses difficultés mais pas à cause de pommes de terre ou de vignes mais bien plutôt à cause des lanières de fouet.

Je crois qu'aujourd'hui, on dirait plus *j'en chie!* (Ne disait-on pas *arra**chier*** aux temps de Villon) Ha! oui! Ego cacas! Pardon Maître!

Comment: Je ne comprends pas pourquoi tu associes _en arracher_ à l'emploi pronominal mais je comprends que c'est pour ça que tu parles du 16e. C'est un peu surprenant ce sens de _avoir été fessé_, l'as-tu rencontré à bien des reprises ? Intéressant.

Comment: **«aux** temps de Villon»??? Est-ce un ancien usage de faire référence à une période aussi courte que la vie d'un homme au pluriel? Ou est-ce une figure de style pour dire que toutes les époques adjacentes au temps dudit Villon étaient si similaires à nos yeux d’homo connecticus qu'elles en sont interchangeables, et que même la découverte imminente de l'Amérique ne suffit pas à marquer une transition digne de mention dans l'histoire humaine? Très belle réponse, par ailleurs (+1).

Comment: @personne : L'histoire serait trop longue à vous conter en commentaires et tl;dr à intégrer à la réponse. Je ne dispose plus non plus de toutes mes sources.

Comment: @Montéedelait : *"Hé ! Dieu, si j'eusse étudié
Au temps de ma jeunesse folle"* Villon a donc eu plusieurs temps non ? ;-) Par ailleurs... Z'avaient qu'à pas découvrir l'Amérique en même temps qu'aller se bagarrer à Constantinople! ;-) et enfin... merci du compliment, vous m'y savez sensible. ;-)